# whats the proper way? sql server and services account

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been reading about how you should set specific service accounts to each sql service, but from what i've read, none have been detailed enough on how to properly create one, would anyone mind explaining what would be the steps on how to create a local, low permission account for the sql service on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Some basic information is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281953.aspx

I tend to make domain user accounts with no particular rights on the network apart from what the account would normally receive (eg domain users).  During SQL Server installation you provide these accoounts to the SQL installer - it will correctly configure the accounts for you (adding them to certain groups, etc).

If you're doing it after SQL installation the correct way to change the service account is to use the SQL Server Configuration Manager (in your start menu) as it will ensure the accounts are, once again, correctly configured.

Using domain accounts is great as you can then grant the service accounts access to particular network shares (backups) and other database servers (linked servers, etc).

As an additional measure if your network resources (file shares, etc) are secured using custom made security groups, rather than "domain users", your SQL Server services won't have access to these areas of the network they shouldn't be able to reach.  I personally haven't tried removing the "domain users" membership - you can't break anything by giving it a go on a VM? :)

Answer (score 0):

This site describes the different options to use the least privileges and the danger of the other options:

- WHEN TO USE DOMAIN USER ACCOUNT?
- WHEN TO USE NETWORK SERVICE ACCOUNT?
  WHEN TO USE LOCAL USER ACCOUNT?
- WHEN TO USE LOCAL SYSTEM ACCOUNT?

### -

-

http://goo.gl/vG55n